# Set media to "Floppy Disk" automatically in Wine

Tags: wine, floppy

In order for an application I am using (with Wine) to be able to access a usb drive I need to set the drive to "floppy disk" in the wine configuration under the drives tab in the advanced settings. If I do this the application works fine. The problem is that I need to do this every time I insert new media into the computer.

Is there a way I can either: force a particular drive letter to default to "floppy disk" or write a script so that new media is altered to floppy if the wine application is open or some other mechanism by which I don't have to reset the media to floppy every time I insert new media? Or even leave a file on the drive so that it's *correctly* recognised by wine as a "floppy disk"?

No the disk isn't actually a floppy disk but this is currently a solution which allows the software to work.

Yes I realise that wine is running correctly and what I query is a work-around.

The software for which this is my current workaround/problem is, two fold: specifically it occurs for both Garmin Basecamp and Garmin mapsource. With much searching, I was only just able to get the software to work at all, and that was by including the workaround described here.

So while this may be an X is Y problem the further workaround I'm requesting would be useful. I can see no solution for the X problem and there may be others potentially who have the same problem for whom this further workaround would also be useful.

Simply put: Can I force Wine to make a drive a "floppy disk" like I do in it's configuration automatically rather than manually?